# "hook from which a body hangs" or "hook on which a body hangs"?

Tags: prepositions

Following a discussion on Russian facebook page, will you say "...hook from which a body hangs" or " ... hook on which a body hangs".  The claim was that both ways are acceptable, is it right?

Comment: And what will be your answer after typo is corrected?

Comment: Your word placement is non idiomatic. I'd say "hook which a body hangs **from/on**". Note that some people say sentences should not end with prepositions, but "that is the sort of nonsense up with which I will not put" *(Winston Churchill quote)*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One subtle difference is whether the object is directly attached to the hook:

- A fish is hanging **on** a hook. (The hook is physically in the fish.)
- A mountain climber is hanging **from** a hook in the cliff.  (A rope connects them.)
- A jacket is hanging **on** a hook.
- A flowerpot is hanging **from** a hook in the ceiling.

Comment: I think you could still be directly attached to a hook, but not have it impale you, and still use **from**, e.g. if there's a hook in the cliff and my fingers are wrapped around it, I'd probably say I was hanging **from** a hook. So for me it's less about direct attachment, and more about impalement.